# Mobile First Responsive Design - How to work on Sidebar or When and Where to hide Sidebar

Tags: responsive-design

I started working on Mobile First Responsive Design. In mobile, there wont be any sidebar but  sidebar is required on desktop so I worked on basic things and then in media query for mobile, hidden that sidebar. Then I needed to make sidebar appear on desktop version of media query.

My question is - How I would have worked on it ?

Answer (score 0):

For the starter, i would like to prefer some basic ideas to build a responsive website:-

1. **Use Layout Flexible**
2. **Donot Use tables**
3. **Use Media Queries**
4. **Use Mobile Viewport Meta Tag**

A basic example for a responsive website is that suppose you have a website with content and sidebar which is floated with 70% and 30% width, in mobile or shrink screens, the content panel and sidebar will be width 100% and float none...

That's a simple example for a responsive website...

Rest you can use framework for responsive websites like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/) and etc...

Comment: I had the specific question and that is more about the approach experts take.

Comment: Approach is as simple as implementation... Mark your implementation first this will surely work for you... Thanks...